# law of laplace and pressure developed in arteries

Tags: physiology, cardiology, biophysics

in arterioles the pressure depends on 
the impedance of the vessel(elasticity and youngs modulus)
cardiac output
pre arteriolar resistance
what i want to ask is will the pressure also depend on law of laplace
for eg.
if a there is peripheral vasodilation( the muscles of the artery wall are relaxed) so the tension is less
the radius is high 
and hence using the equation( pressure=2*tension/r)
the pressure in the arteriole is low
is this arguememt valid??